# Geometry Nodes: Is there any way to move the X, Y, and Y separately with attributes in the Point Translate node

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

Hello.

How could I drive each of the X, Y, and Z axis of the Point Translate node with an attribute that I created in a previous node (you can see it in the included image).

I am using Blender 3.0.0 Cycles X build.

I am ok with switching to a daily build with maybe a new feature to fix this.
I could use a plugin but would like to avoid it.

And I included a picture for you to see the problem.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

PS: If the question is not clear just say and I will try to improve it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in 2.93, but it should work just fine in 3.0:

[image]

We decompose position into individual XYZ attributes; we multiply our height by an arbitrary "slope" value; we add our modified height to our X position; we recompose our position attribute.

Comment: Thank you.
This is not exactly what I wanted because I actualy wanted to use the _Z_ location as the slope but, I learned with this about the _Attribute Combine XYZ_ and could make with this what I wanted.